# Why is WPBakery Page Builder backend editor not clickable?

Tags: plugins, editor, visual-editor

The backend editor button is not clickable.

I've tried to change all files/folders attributes to 777 for this plugin.
I've checked and increased some php parameters (phpinfo for my site - https://avtovoronka.su/php.php)
I disabled all other plugins and changed themes.
Changed the plugin to older versions.

Button still is not clickable. How can I fixed it?

There is another installed plugin (Hustle, for popups) that has the same problem - its dashboard even is not loading.

Console
[image]

Comment: Zip https://avtovoronka.su/js_composer-56.zip

Comment: I've attached screenshot from console, There's nothing about the page builder

Comment: I did this many times and tried to install old versions. still not working

Comment: I think something wrong with server settings or ssl

Comment: I've renamed already

Comment: Thank you very much for your attempts, I've changed all attributes (for this plugin) to 777, but page builder still isn't working

Comment: No. Sorry, I can't give ftp, I connect with sftp to whole server and there many websites that aren't mine

Comment: So, what is my issue? Do you know why editor isn't working? You can write here and I will do